# How to install custom plugin on outlook (for mac)?

Tags: outlook-addin

I have created a simple plugin and installed it on my outlook (for windows). It works fine. However i want to know - can I install the same plugin on outlook (for Mac)? If so, Please guide. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Office/Outlook for Mac doesn't support add-ins. The COM technology (on which Office add-ins are based) is for Windows only.

The only possible option is to develop a VBA macro instead.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Astafiev, I will try to devlop a VBA macro for both the environments

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev, are you sure about this? Could you please give me link on information source?.

Comment: Yes, I am. The latest version of Office for MAC also supports Mail Apps. That is all.